# Adding Navigation Effect to tableView reloading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am working on

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (!XAppDelegate.isRegular) 
{
    if([self shouldReloadWithSubCategory:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[categoriesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"CategoryId"]]])
    {
       [KeysArray addObject:categoriesArray];
       categoriesArray = [categoriesContainer objectForKey:key];
       NSLog(@"%@",categoriesArray);
       [tv reloadData];
    }
} }
```

I have a category and sub category. when select on a category, sub category is appeared on same view controller by reloading tableView. I want to see navigation effect when we push a view controller to navigationControoler, but without using another view controller. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you don't want to use another view controller.

Comment: this should solve your problem 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906345/adding-navigation-controller-push-or-any-effetct-on-tableview-reload

Answer (score 0):

There are much more code for this implementation. Too easy create another `DetailTableViewController`.
But if you want to realize using you rules:

1) I must create any flag that means `Common view OR Detail view`
2) Create containers for categories and subcategory.
3) Dependency flag load different resource in data source. 
4) Reload table view

To get navigation effect, try to push `self`. If it not resolve you problem - create new object with correct fields.